# Read files downloaded from in-app purchase server

Tags: ios, path, download, in-app-purchase

I want to build an app which looks like ibook for ipad, but now I don't know if my user has downloaded a book from my in-App purchase server, where can I find the book's file in my programme. in another words, Need I set the path for the files which will be download, or the os will help me save it at somewhere???

if you know the details of the programming or anything else, please show it for me, thankyou！！！

Answer (score 0):

iOS will not help you track if a user has downloaded a file or not - you need to keep track of this in your app. You can allow users to "restore purchases", but that will just check if the in-app purchase has been made or not - it will not check if a user has already downloaded a file.

Check this guide on how the entire process works, in-app purchase with downloads:

http://xinsight.ca/blog/iap-content-download-in-ios6/

On another note: Apples guidelines state that if you have a book, you should publish it on iBookstore, not as an app.